# How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => abc
        [1] => def
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => ghi
        [1] => jkl
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => mno
        [1] => pql
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => abc
        [1] => def
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => ghi
        [1] => jkl
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
        [0] => mno
        [1] => pql
    )
)
```

Comment: Copy Pasted the question. I mean what are you experimenting ?

Comment: completely duplicate

Comment: A duplicate question about duplicate values is funny, but this isn't a comedy site.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: As far as I know, this does not work on multidimensional

Answer (score 0):

Would use a nested foreach like follows:

```
foreach ($aArray as $iPos => $aInnerArray) {

    foreach ($aArray as $iPos => $aArrayToCheck) {

        if($aInnerArray === $aArrayToCheck){

            unset($aArray($iPos));

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
//method for remove duplicate data
function removeDuplicate($arr) {
    //Define output
    $outputs = [];

    //Define temp for keep data
    $tmps    = [];

    foreach ($arr as $each) {
        //convert to string
        $tmp = implode("|", $each);

        if (!in_array($tmp, $tmps)) {
            $tmps[] = $tmp;
            $outputs[] = $each;
        }
    }
    return $outputs;
}
```